# How to save some images of dataset?

Tags: python, dataset

I have a big dataset, i want just to save only images  that end with 07 in new folder and delete the _crop_128.
can you help me to write  this script in python.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Za2x.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have a dataset which contain 130000 images , i want just to choose images that ended names is ..._07_crop_128.png.// then i want to delete _crop_128 to be ..._07.png